# Java socketserver how to test?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, text-files

I want to receive text files through a socket connection in java, I set up the server end but before I continue with the client I would like to know if the code I made works, except I have no idea how to test this.

Any help would be much appreciated..

EDIT: I know the port is open and listening for requests, what i want is to test what happens if it receives anything, will it create a file from the input and can I test this by simulation(sending a file or bytes i dont know)?

```
public class Server {

    private static int port = 8080;
    private static int maxConnections = 100000;

    // Listen for incoming connections and handle them
    public static void startServer() {
        int i = 0;

        try {
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket server;

            System.out.println("Started server on port:" + port);

            while ((i++ < maxConnections) || (maxConnections == 0)) {
                RunServer connection;

                server = listener.accept();
                RunServer conn_c = new RunServer(server);
                Thread t = new Thread(conn_c);
                t.start();

                System.out.println("Created new thread");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class RunServer implements Runnable {
    private Socket server;

    RunServer(Socket server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    public void run() {
        int bytesRead;
        int current = 0;
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        DataInputStream clientData = null;
        File file = null;

        try {
            // creating connection.
            System.out.println("connected.");

            // receive file
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[6022386];
            System.out.println("Please wait downloading file");

            // reading file from socket
            InputStream inputStream = server.getInputStream();
            file = new File("toread.txt");
            clientData = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            bytesRead = inputStream.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

            current = bytesRead;
            do {
                bytesRead = inputStream.read(byteArray, current, (byteArray.length - current));
                if (bytesRead >= 0)
                    current += bytesRead;
            } while (bytesRead > -1);

            bufferedOutputStream.write(byteArray, 0, current);
            bufferedOutputStream.flush();

            ReaderHelper.readTextFile(file);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fileOutputStream != null)
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                if (bufferedOutputStream != null)
                    bufferedOutputStream.close();
                if (clientData != null)
                    clientData.close();
                if (server != null)
                    server.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you, by chance, want to unit test this code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your socket will be up on port 8080 right?

You can open your browser and type: http://localhost:8080. The browser will create a connection and the line

> server = listener.accept();

will "unlock". If you just wanna test if the socket is listenning it will do. Reading the stream you will see the first message of the HTTP protocol.

Comment: I know the port is open and listening for requests, what i want is to test what happens if it receives anything, will it create a file from the input and can I test this by simulation(sending a file or bytes i dont know how to simulate this)?

Answer (score 0):

At first you have a possible error in a reading loop

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[6022386];
//some code
do {
    bytesRead = inputStream.read(byteArray, current, (byteArray.length - current));
    if (bytesRead >= 0)
        current += bytesRead;
} while (bytesRead > -1);
```

If file length is more than `byteArray.length` which is possible, then `(byteArray.length - current)` would be negative.

I suggest you to use smaller array, e.g. `byte[] byteArray = new byte[8192];` and read file like this

```
while ((bytesRead = in.read(byteArray)) > 0 ) {
    current += bytesRead;
    bufferedOutputStream.write(byteArray, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

storing it into disk chunk by chunk. And after exiting while loop `current` will hold total number of read bytes.

Send file from another thread, which will connect to server

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", Server.port);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream("fileName");
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while(fileInput.read(buffer) != -1){
    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
//close resources
```